# How to back up the .vhd files of virtual box before deleting and replacing messed bin/sh and bin/dash?

Tags: virtualbox

How can I back up my .vhd files ? Can I just to copy and paste into another location of my hard disk.. before I do 
`cd /bin
sudo rm sh
sudo ln -s dash sh` to recover back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VirtualBox allows you to take snapshots of your virtual machines.

[image: snapshot.png]

Create a snapshot of the machine before you make the changes. If the changes destroy your virtual machine, you can simply revert back to the snapshot you took.

Comment: I have .vhd files of snapshots.. but the OS is not booting... it is asking me to install ubuntu on the machine... if i do so.. can i add my old snapshots to the newly installed ubuntu?

Comment: I've never actually tried something like that, but I seriously doubt it would work. Snapshots typically work by layering changes (in a separate file) over the original disk file. Your new system would have to match exactly (probably down to the bits) the system that the snapshots were taken from. The chances of setting up something like that are improbable.

Comment: okay thankyou... the problem was that ubuntu is not booting up and it is taking me to a screen where I should install my ubuntu again ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes i created a new machine and added the copy of my .vhd from my snapshot instead of creating new space on the hard disk (a new .vhd) it worked, I could get all the data from my snapshot